# Angular: When using mat-select , Is there a way to not select the focused item when I press SPACE button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select, mat-option

By looking at, https://v5.material.angular.io/components/select/overview 
There are several keyboard interactions.

- Keyboard interaction
- DOWN_ARROW: Focus next option
- UP_ARROW: Focus previous option
- ENTER or SPACE: Select focused item

I am able to stop the whole interaction, BUT what I want is:  
**keep the all the keyboard interactions, except the SPACE one**

Is there a way to do it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take account the Georg-un's answer

But if there a great great reason you always can "re-writte" the function.

Use a template reference variable in your select

```
<mat-select #select="matSelect">
   ...
</mat-select>
```

And you can use ViewChild to get the mat select and rewrite the function

```
  @ViewChild('select', { static: true }) select: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.select._handleKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.keyCode==SPACE)
        return
      if (!this.select.disabled) {
        this.select.panelOpen
          ? this.select._handleOpenKeydown(event)
          : this.select._handleClosedKeydown(event);
      }
    };
  }
```

NOTE: SPACE is defined in

```
import { SPACE} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
```

**Update** we can use a directive also

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[no-space]',
})
export class NoSpaceDirective {
  @Output('spacekeydown') spacekeydown: EventEmitter<any> =
    new EventEmitter<any>();
    
constructor(@Self() private select: MatSelect) {
    this.select._handleKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.keyCode == SPACE) {
          const active=this.select.panelOpen?
                 this.select.options.filter(x=>x.active)[0]|| null:
                 null
        this.spacekeydown.emit(active?active.value:null);
      } else {
        if (!this.select.disabled) {
          this.select.panelOpen
            ? (this.select as any)._handleOpenKeydown(event)
            : (this.select as any)._handleClosedKeydown(event);
        }
      }
    };
  }

}
```

And you use as

```
<mat-select no-space 
     (spacekeydown)="doSomething($event)">
   ...
</mat-select>
```

As always, if we use as "selector" instead `[no-space]` `mat-select`

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-select',
})
...
```

The directive is applied to all ours mat-select

see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-wgepy2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fno-space.directive.ts) with the directive

Comment: It's working! Thanks a lot for the help. It's my first overriding the function from source code.  Learned something new today!

Comment: @zhinee, I update the answer to indicate how do it using a directive. I hope this can help you

Comment: Interesting, never thought I could use directive to achieve this functionality. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

I think this is related and it might be of interest to someone who has an input field in `mat-select` and needs to disable the closing of `mat-select` when the user presses a space in the input. You just need to prevent default behavior on click and keydown:

```
<mat-select>
    <mat-option
        <input 
            (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
            (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        </input>
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: `(keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"` did the trick for me... I used this bit of code to focus on the input field whilst user is typing some values.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/select/select.ts#L718), you'll find that the keys are hardcoded. Therefore, you cannot easily override them.

Besides that, you probably should not override them anyways sice this would conflict with accessibility.

Comment: really it's very easy override the function. just use ViewChild and re-define the function. But I'm agree with you about accessibility

Comment: Not a big fan of overriding private functions of other libraries if it is not absolutely necessary. In most cases it's just technical debt for the guy after you to take care of. But you are absolutely right that it can be overridden. In the end, its just javascript anyways.

Comment: I general I agree with you, but you can improve some material components. e.g. you want to use F1 in the mat-select to show aditional information or you can change the icons of the mat-sort in a table...

Answer (score 0):

@Eliseo answer is correct.
Unfortunately, in Angular 16, _handleOpenKeydown & _handleClosedKeydown method are marked as private.

My way out to override the function is calling the parent's method.
And I can't use event.keyCode because it is deprecated. So I need to use event.key.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.select._handleKeydown = (event:KeyboardEvent)=>{
        if (event.key === ' ' ) return
        MatSelect.prototype._handleKeydown.call(this.select, event)
    }
}
```